# How to make a forest plot from logistic regression results before and after adjusting for covariates

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-forestplot

I have a result that I intend to have a forest plot from. This is the result of logistic regression (OR[95%CI]) in which I examined the association of three groups with several treatments before and after adjustment for covariates. The table is as follows. I used the following codes but the result of before and after are shown as merged lines without any labels that make the figure difficult to understand. How can I split the figure to before and after adjustment results?

| Treatment | OR | Low_CI | High_CI | P_value | Group | Adjustment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.78 | 0.64 | 0.94 | 0.011 | 1 | Before |
| B | 0.91 | 0.84 | 0.98 | 0.025 | 1 | Before |
| C | 1.63 | 1.19 | 2.21 | 0.0019 | 2 | Before |
| A | 1.24 | 1.03 | 1.50 | 0.02 | 2 | Before |
| C | 0.46 | 0.25 | 0.79 | 0.008 | 4 | Before |
| B | 0.88 | 0.79 | 0.98 | 0.025 | 1 | After |
| C | 1.72 | 1.19 | 2.44 | 0.002 | 2 | After |
| D | 0.89 | 0.79 | 0.99 | 0.03 | 2 | After |
| c | 0.48 | 0.23 | 0.87 | 0.027 | 4 | After |

```
data$Sortnum <- nrow(data) - as.numeric(rownames(data))
data$Label <- fct_reorder(data$Treatment,data$Sortnum)

ggplot(data ,aes(x=Label, y=OR, color =Group )) +  geom_point(size=1) + geom_line(size=2) + coord_flip() + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Low.CI, ymax=Up.CI),width=0.2,cex=1, color = 'gray50')+ ylab("OR(95% Confidence Interval)")+ geom_hline(aes(fill = Label),yintercept =1, linetype=2)+ facet_grid(Group~., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y") + scale_alpha_identity()+ scale_y_log10(breaks=c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4, 1.6,  2.0, 2.4),position="left",limits=c(0.2,2.5))+ theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),axis.title=element_text(size=20),text = element_text(size=18), axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=16),axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black",size=20), legend.position=c(0.25, 0.2), legend.title=element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(size=16), legend.background = element_rect(color = "black",fill = "white", size = 0.3, linetype = "solid")
  )
```

Comment: There's no clear definition of what a "good" plot is. If you tell us what plot you want exactly, then we might be able to help. If you just want to talk more generally about data visualization, that's more on topic for [stats.se] than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Where is the code you used to make your plot? Please show your attempt so we may fix what’s wrong.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to change about the current plot to "include after adjustment results"? Also your sample data is a bit unclear. Is that one table with duplicate column names? A proper data frame cannot have duplicate column names because then it's not possible to specify exactly which column you want.

Comment: I voted to reopen, but you need more votes before it can be changed. I think you still have a problem with not being clear what the desired output is, but overall the question has been improved. Stack overflow is not the right place for time sensitive needs so that's not really considered when deciding if a question should be reopened or not.